# is fm transmitters legal in japan

Tags: legal, fm, transmitter, japan

I was wondering what the laws are in Japan concerning FM Transmitters. I recently purchased one of eBay (http://www.ebay.com/itm/401047827071)
I don't have a license or anything so I would like to know if I can legally use it.

Answer (score 3):

Usually these type of questions are not easy to answer precisely.

Generally speaking countries allow certain low-power devices to transmit within the FM-broadcast band, pending type-approval of the device. (e.g. the device must be tested and found to be OK according to specifications)

There are resources which can be found on the internet, such as [this](http://www.teleconformity.com/index?page=japan), which lists the following:

> As specified in the Radio Law, Extremely Weak (low) Power Equipment
>   and Receivers must comply with the Japanese Radio Regulations, but do
>   not require registration at MIC. Examples of products requiring
>   performance of compliancy with the emission limits, are FM modulators
>   and radio Receivers. Teleconformity offers Performance Certification,
>   including testing.

You do need to ask yourself how much "authority" these resources have in these cases.

It seems that there is some sort of "*certification*" needed for low power devices, from MIC.

You could ofcourse contact [MIC](http://www.soumu.go.jp/english/) (Ministry of Internal Affairs and Communications) to get further information.

*... maybe someone with more specific knowledge about Japanese legislation can give you a more precise answer...*